# How to make TextView looks exactly like EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

How to make the whole TextView underline at the width of match parent like EditText?

This line of code only underlines the text, not the whole TextView.

```
textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

The reason I want to use TextView is that setOnClickListener is triggered immediately in one tap for TextView, whereas two taps are required for a disabled editable EditText.

Comment: If you want something to look like an EditText but not be editable you should use an edittext and disable it. Then it will also have the right text color suggesting to the user that it is not editable.

Comment: The reason I want to use TextView is that setOnClickListener is triggered immediately in one tap for TextView, whereas two taps are required for a disabled editable EditText.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can put the background of an EditText on your TextView. For example:

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your text"
            android:hint="My hint"
            android:textColor="?attr/editTextColor"
            android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
            />
```

You might want to change the text appearance to `android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"` if you are using an AppCompat theme.

Comment: `android:background="?attr/editTextBackground"` is the answer for my question. Thank you very much, this is helpful.

Comment: amazing , you saved my time

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same but for the ReadOnly EditText style? When the TextView is not editable, the underline should gray-out like with a regular EditText that is "setEnable(false) && setClickable(false)". Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve this without writing many lines of xml attributes:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your text"
        android:hint="Your hint"
        style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
        />
```

Comment: From what I've noticed, applying `style` as you proposed changes `TextView`'s behavior and visual style into `EditText` instead of just applying visual style. Keyboard is showing, you can enter text and `onClick` is fired after second click on this control.
Applying style would have more sense if you defined your own style based on TextView with attributes mentioned above.